# onClick event isn't called on Safari when the button has "display: contents"

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

**onClick** event isn't called on Safari **(iPhone)** when the button has **"display: contents"**

here's an example for testing

https://codepen.io/RAFAELVCARMO/pen/JjdOYYX

```
<div>
  <button class="contentsButton" onClick="alert('test')">
    <div>
      Test
    </div>
  </button>
</div>

.contentsButton {
  display: contents;

  > div {
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
}
```

is there an workaround?

Comment: Actually, it worked

Comment: did it work on iphone?

Comment: Yep, it did. :)

Comment: in my tests, it worked with a longer touch, but not with a simple touch... how did u do?

Comment: Just a simple touch

Comment: Which is your iOS and Safari version?

Comment: Latest. Everything is up-to-date.